# Concat ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments, problem with TO_DATE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have problem with using to_date inside `CONCAT`.

Here is an example of my query:

```
SELECT s.*, CONCAT('TO_DATE(' , s.created , ',''DD.MM.RRRR'')') AS CREATED 
FROM SHIPMENT s
```

With this query I get an error

> invalid number of arguments

and I don't know how to fix that...

Comment: What do you want to concat ?

Comment: and why do you want to concat..? To be able to use within a string such as `execute immediate ' select s.*, concat..... '`..? Please be explicit, and reveal clearly what you wanna do. Btw,  what's the data type of `created` column ..?

Comment: Are you sure you do not simply want `TO_DATE(s.created, 'DD.MM.RRRR')`?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.

Comment: @Radagast81 yes i am pretty sure) i need that for insert to another database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concat takes two parameters. you can use double pipe to concat or call concat twice to concatenate 3 string.

```
SELECT s.*, 'TO_DATE(' || s.created || ',''DD.MM.RRRR'')' AS CREATED FROM SHIPMENT s
```

or

```
SELECT s.*, CONCAT(CONCAT('TO_DATE(', s.created), ',''DD.MM.RRRR'')') AS CREATED FROM SHIPMENT s
```